# still read cached file after delete require.cache in node.js

Tags: node.js, chokidar

I user chokdir and watch to specific folder and after changes, i delete some cached files like this:

```
  const pathName = path.join(__dirname, '../api');
  const watcher = chokidar.watch(pathName);

  watcher.on('ready', () => {
    watcher.on('all', () => {
      console.log('Clearing module cache from server');
      Object.keys(require.cache).forEach((id) => {
        if (/[\/\\]api[\/\\]/.test(id)) {
          delete require.cache[id]
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

in chrome inspector, when i inspect to my code i see my api changed correctly, but when i run my api i get a old file with ***yellow background color*** like this:
my controller name is *HomeController* but after file changed, i see ***VM1407 HomeController***
do you know what is the problem? and what is VM before my controller name?

[image]

Comment: Where are the modules you are attempting to reload required? If they aren't locally required, that is required at the top of the file, removing them from the cache will have no effect as the return value of the require is cached in the module scope variable.

Comment: @DanD.Thanks, what do you mean of locally required? could you please give me an example?